# How to create tables in SQL database for the following situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, system

I am developing a system to calculate SMV of a garment. I am facing issues to create tables in my database. I want to insert operations for a style. There can be different number of operations for different styles.

I have already created a table called `StyleDetails` which consiste the `style no, account, buyer` etc. except the operations.

For example the operations for style no A444 can be like below:

```
join neck,
attach neck,
attch sleeve,
bottom hem...etc.
```

How do I design my database to input such operations for the relevant styles. Pls reply soon.

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: So you have one to many between StyleDetails and Operation? What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear, I think you should take a look at how Bill of Materials ("BOM") database designs work. I'm not sure what database platform you are working with but there are many tutorials on this topic. [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/11/06/bill-of-materials-the-basics.aspx) is one.